# URL Rewriter Expression

Tags: regex, urlrewriter

My current rewriter working well but when a user comment on facebook and facebook append an URL on it, it can not load anymore.

This is my expression:

```
<rewrite url="~/hinh-anh/(.+)-(.+)" to="~/Content.aspx?ContentID=$2"/>
```

This is working well:

```
http://www.funbook.vn/hinh-anh/pho-cu-reu-phong-205
```

This URL doesn't work:

```
http://www.funbook.vn/hinh-anh/pho-cu-reu-phong-205?fb_comment_id=fbc_10151011439516616_22968658_10151011472976616#f17f94926c
```

Please help me, I am noob at regular expression.

Thank in advance!!

Edited:

Finally I found solution:

```
<rewrite url="~/hinh-anh/([A-Za-z\-]*)([\d]+)" to="~/Content.aspx?ContentID=$2"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
<rewrite url="~/hinh-anh/(.+)-(.+).*" to="~/Content.aspx?ContentID=$2"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found solution:

```
`<rewrite url="~/hinh-anh/([A-Za-z\-]*)([\d]+)" to="~/Content.aspx?ContentID=$2"/>`
```